# Adding the illusion of age in a text based game

Tags: c#

so i'm developing a text based game in C#, i've currently got it laid out that a person will spawn as a class in the main body of the code (Person.cs). This person has an age inside the class that is randomly picked in the generator (int between 1 - 500), This will also include random enemies (Enemy.cs : Person) and maybe a partner or two on the way(Person.cs).

I want a way that when certain things happen everyone inside the program will all change age (people, pets). I dont want it based on the PC clock (think a magician that can change time forwards or backwards).

I setup a class for TimeManager.cs which just has an int inside it and i can obviously modify that, I just haven't got a way to push the date/age to all the other classes. I'd rather not hardcode a limit on how many of anything you can have if that makes sense

Have i overlooked something simple ? Cheers

Comment: Don't you have a list of characters in the game? Then you could just iterate over the List<Person> and set each one's age. I'm not sure what the problem is...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the game seems really interresting!

Every element that can age must implement the interface `Ageable` or something, forcing them to implement a method that makes them change age.

Once you have this, keep a `List<Agable>` somewhere in your code, for example in the `World` class that is closely related to your main class and reachable directly or indirectly by all your `Magician`s.

Once your want to change the age of all the `Ageable`, simply tell your `World` to iterate on the list and call all the methods that make your living creatures older or younger.

Comment: Thank you, this actually turned out to be a super simple answer to a stupid question from me. Coming from python i forget that Lists<> can be more than they are

Answer (score 3):

You can determine my age using my date of birth. Why? Because you know the current date. It seems that you would be better served by tracking the "time" when an entity was created, and then comparing that with the current "time" in order to produce an age.

The reason why I believe this approach is better comes down to the fact that you have many elements, and would have to otherwise visit each of them in turn to change their age when an aging event happens. It seems unlikely that you will need to calculate the age of a large number of entities simultaneously, so calculating the age like this will probably result in less overall work.

Consider your time service:

```
public class TimeService
{
    public int CurrentYear { get; private set; }

    public void IncrementYear()
    {
        ++CurrentYear;
    }

    public void DecrementYear()
    {
        --CurrentYear;
    }
}
```

And your entity:

```
public class Entity
{
    public int CreatedYear { get; set; }
}
```

You can determine the age as follows:

```
int age = timeService.CurrentYear - entity.CreatedYear;
```

If you don't want negative ages, you may want to wrap this in a `Math.Max();` between `0` and `age` to ensure that the minimum age is 0.

You could wrap this calculation into a method, perhaps on the time service:

```
public int GetAge(Entity e)
{
    return Math.Max(0, this.CurrentYear - entity.CreatedYear);
}
```